# software-properties-common installation fails on polkitd_0.105-33_amd64.deb

Tags: networking, server, software-installation

```
# apt install software-properties-common
Err:81 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 polkitd amd64 0.105-33                                                             
  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/policykit-1/polkitd_0.105-33_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-cryptography/python3-cryptography_3.4.8-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-httplib2/python3-httplib2_0.20.2-2_all.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-zipp/python3-zipp_1.0.0-3_all.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jeepney/python3-jeepney_0.7.1-3_all.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
```